# jQuery dialog + ASP.NET buttons - strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Having this div:

```
<div id="advSearchDialog" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <xx:search ID="searchUC" runat="server" />
</div>
```

And a button:

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdvSearch" value="Search" />
```

I turn it into a jQuery dialog, where the button opens the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#advSearchDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true,
        title: 'Avanceret søgning',
        open: function(type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });

    $('#btnAdvSearch').click(function() {
        $('#advSearchDialog').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#advSearchDialog').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Using ASP.NET, I get a problem.

If I push some other button on the ASP.NET page (inside an update panel), and after that clicks the btnAdvSearch button, nothing happens. Why is that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe the partial page refresh removes your click event, hard to say without seeing the whole page.

the solutions to that problem would be using jquery live events
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

hth

Comment: you could also put your jQuery dialog code in the pageLoad function, this will be called on every partial postback by asp.net ajax (http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx)

Comment: Using live events did the trick. Thank you very much marc. Simple and easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the emitted HTML using firebug or somthing similar and you will probably notice that your button is no longer inside the form tags and is at the end of the body tag.

In you're OK button callback you can use something like

```
dialogBox.appendTo($('#FormIdHere'));
```

dialogBox is a variable set as so

```
var dialogBox = $('#DialogDiv').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
```

This should add your button back into the form.

EDIT:

Here is a code snippet I've recently used (all the code below is fired within an onload function but reasonPostBack must be declared outside the onload function)

```
var button = $('input.rejectButton');
reasonPostBack = button.attr('onclick');
button.removeAttr('onclick');

var dialogBox = $('#ReasonDiv').dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: 'Please enter a reason', modal: true, bgiframe: true, buttons: { "Ok": function() {

            if ($('input.reasonTextBox').val().length > 0) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                dialogBox.appendTo($('#theform'));
                reasonPostBack();
            }
            else 
            {
                  alert('You must enter a reason for rejection');
            }
        }
    }
});


button.click(function() {
    dialogBox.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

First i take a reference to the .Net postback with

```
var reasonPostBack = button.attr('onclick');
```

and hold it for later then strip the click event from the button to stop the post back ocurring "automatically".  I then build the dialog box and add an anonymous function for the OK button, this runs my code to test if there is anything in a text box, if there isn't it simply alerts the user otherwise it;

Closes the div

```
$(this).dialog('close');
```

Adds the div back inside the form tags ready for the post back

```
dialogBox.appendTo($('#theform'));
```

and then calls the original postback

```
reasonPostBack();
```

Finally the last bit of code

```
button.click(function() {
    dialogBox.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

adds our own event handler to the .Net button to open the dialog that was instantiated earlier.

HTH

OneSHOT